# upload file in chrome needs to open finder dialog twice to find all files

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome

Whenever I add a file to my new Mac (Big Sur) by for instance taking a screenshot, and go to upload it through chrome, the file isn't there when the upload dialog first comes up. if I close that dialog and click the upload button again as to bring up the upload dialog anew, the recently added file is there.

Seems like the first dialog performs a search for new files, but those are only shown once the dialog is brought up again.

Permission setting or what causes this odd behavior? My old Mac doesn't have this behavior at all (Catalina).

Also, many files (but not the folders) are "greyed out" in the upload dialog, but they are all selectable.

In this scenario I have 3 screenshots (filename "skärmavbild..."), but the first time I open the dialog I only see two of them, not the most recently added...

[image]

I close the dialog and immediately open it up again and this is what I get

[image]

Not sure if it is browser-related or macOS related...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in macOS that's been around for many months already. Until they bother to fix it there's isn't really anything you can do.

As a workaround, you can use the back/forward buttons and the files will show as they are supposed to. (If the back/forward buttons are disabled, press Cmd+Up to go up a directory then you can press back.)

Comment: How can I repo this bug? I don't see it. I press Shift-Cmd-4, then space, then click a window. A screenshot is taken and a thumbnail appears for a few moments. I click the image icon in stackoverflow and then the "add picture" button. I see the most recent screenshot in the open dialog. I'm on MacOS 11.4

Comment: I must have partially misread the question, my answer was about the greyed-out files, not missing files themselves. However it does seem the greyed-out issue has been fixed (although files are still grey for a split second when opening a folder).